Copying a rectangle image of transformed/rotated Graphics (Bitmap) into another transformed/rotated Graphics object
The functionality I want to achieve, is being able to copy a rectangle off of a part of image and pasting that part to another same dimension image in the same place. I want to use it to blur parts of the image that might contain some sensitive data, while simultaneously have the ability to make some of that data visible. Let's take this image for example:

I want to blur the vehicles and people, but still want to have License plates visible. The first part is easily done with:
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage))
{
    g.DrawImage(firstImage, item.Rect, item.Rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

I create a replica of this image, that is blurred, and then just copy those parts.
The Result is this:

The interesting part begins - when the rectangle I want to copy are rotated. License plates in this case. I've tried multiple approaches, but failed entirely. first approach was this:
    public static void CopyAndRotateImage(Bitmap fromBitmap, Graphics destGraphics, Rectangle rect, float rotationAngle)
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(fromBitmap))
    {
        g.TranslateTransform(rect.X + rect.Width / 2, rect.Y);
        g.RotateTransform(+rotationAngle);
        g.TranslateTransform(-rect.X - rect.Width / 2, -rect.Y);

        destGraphics.TranslateTransform(rect.X + rect.Width / 2, rect.Y);
        destGraphics.RotateTransform(+rotationAngle);
        destGraphics.TranslateTransform(-rect.X - rect.Width / 2, -rect.Y);

        destGraphics.DrawImage(fromBitmap, rect, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        g.ResetTransform();
        destGraphics.ResetTransform();
    }
}

It goes to the middle of the rectangle, rotates everything, goes back into the same place and does the copying. This approach looked good on paper, but the end result in destGraphics is the primary image without any rotation.

That means, that bitmap and Graphics are not interconnected fully. The transformation methods seem to have no effect on the Bitmap. So - I've looked up what I can find and later found, that I can created new Bitmap from the Graphics object:
public static void CopyAndRotateImage(Bitmap fromBitmap, Graphics destGraphics, Rectangle rect, float rotationAngle)
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(fromBitmap))
    {
        g.TranslateTransform(rect.X + rect.Width / 2, rect.Y);
        g.RotateTransform(+rotationAngle);
        g.TranslateTransform(-rect.X - rect.Width / 2, -rect.Y);

        destGraphics.TranslateTransform(rect.X + rect.Width / 2, rect.Y);
        destGraphics.RotateTransform(+rotationAngle);
        destGraphics.TranslateTransform(-rect.X - rect.Width / 2, -rect.Y);

        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fromBitmap.Width, fromBitmap.Height, g))
        {
            destGraphics.DrawImage(bitmap, rect, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        g.ResetTransform();
        destGraphics.ResetTransform();
    }
}

But in this case - it seems, that the Bitmap that was created, was only of the resolution of the Graphics object, and did not take any data from Graphics object. I've been looking at Documentations, asking ChatGbt, but I couldn't find a way to achieve what I'm trying to do. Any ideas would help.

Some example images might be useful. If you want to do something fancy you might either need to either use an intermediate buffer to draw to, or to manipulate the alpha-channel to get finer control of the pixels to copy.

"was only of the resolution of the Graphics object, and did not take any data from Graphics object" - Yes, that is the specified behavior of that constructor. If you wanted it to contain the drawn data you should have created the graphics object from that bitmap.
